# stop the calendar control in asp,net from doing a postback everytime the month is changed

Tags: asp.net

The Calendar control in asp.net has a default behaviour to do a postback whenever the month is changed (when clicking on next or previous month arrows). This causes the calendar control to collapse. How to prevent this. I want a postback only when the date selection changes and the calendar control should not collapse when month is changed.

Any help is appreciated

thanks in advance

Comment: Use a clientside calendar, for example http://marcgrabanski.com/articles/jquery-ui-datepicker

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like there is some other code on your page that is not postback aware that is causing the calendar control to collapse. The calendar control is a serverside control that will cause postbacks to change the month, year, etc.

One thing to try would be to put the calendar control on an ajax updatepanel. The post back will still occur, but it will be done within the context of the panel and should not fire all the other page events on the return trip.

I also agree with Tim's advice that you could use a client side date picker. If you are not doing anything interesting on the code behind with the control, it's not adding any value.

Comment: My calendar control is inside a div tag. Here is the code below.