# asp.net calendar PostBack

Tags: asp.net, calendar

I have a button that once I click it should show the calendar, and when I click the button again the calendar should disappear  using this simple JavaScript code

```
function ShowCal() {

var calender = document.getElementById("Calendar1");
if (calender.style.display == "none")
{ 
calender.style.display = "inline"; 
}
else { calender.style.display = "none" }
}
```

My problem is the postback, everytime I click 'Next' so I can view the next calendar month, the whole calendar disappears.

How can I stop my page from refreshing and going back to the top of the page?

Comment: If your calendar control isn't a client-side control, it will be hard, if even possible... It's always quite complicated making .NET and javascript act together on the same control. You should try using ASP.NET only methods, or javascript methods, not mix.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Calendar control without postback](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20581764/calendar-control-without-postback), http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9860045/stop-the-calendar-control-in-asp-net-from-doing-a-postback-everytime-the-month-i, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5140200/to-disable-autopostback-for-calender-control-in-asp-net

Comment: When you click "next" and the page posts back, what causes the calendar to disappear?  Is it styled to be hidden by default when the page loads?  If so, then in your server-side event handler for that particular event just set it to not be hidden.

Comment: Show us the html so we can see the calendar's default settings.

Comment: Thanks for all your responses guys, what I have decided to do is, remove the JavaScript code and just decided to use the server side and set it to not be hidden as suggested by David. So when the button is clicked the calender will show up and once a date has been clicked the calendar will disappear